# How to run h2o AutoML by using rest api?

Tags: rest, h2o, automl

I want run AutoML in h2o by using rest api? I know the url is /99/AutoMLBuilder. But I have no idea that how can I send the parameters. There is no sample code on the official web site. I can access model import/export by using curl because the parameters are flat. But it seems that maybe the parameters of AutoML are nested, and I cannot find any sample code or answers about the format of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are sent in JSON format through a POST command. For example, assuming a training frame named `airlines` has already been loaded, you can train an AutoML model through curl with:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:54321/99/AutoMLBuilder -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"input_spec": {"training_frame":"airlines", "response_column":"IsDepDelayed"}, "build_control": {"project_name":"aml_curl_test", "stopping_criteria":{"max_models":3} } }'
```

You can find the full REST API reference here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/rest-api-reference.html, which will tell you the JSON object names each parameter belongs to.